# getting JSON feed working inside AsyncTask but not in oncreate

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

Hello I have to fetch a JSON feed and that's why I am using this code:

```
try {

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(
                new BasicHttpParams());
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(CommonUtils.URL);
        httpget.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + CommonUtils.BEARER_TOKEN);
        httpget.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        inputStream = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("GetFeedTask", "Error:" + e.getMessage());
    }
```

This is working when I used this code inside `AsyncTask` and call it in `onCreate()` but is not working and throw Exception **`GetFeedTask`** when I call it directly in `onCreate()`. What's the problem?

Logcat:

```
GetFeedTask  Error: null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By running the code directly in `onCreate()` you are attempting to do network communications on the UI thread. Android does not allow networking on the main thread and will throw a `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`. You are catching a type `Exception` which is for all run time errors - otherwise your program would crash with the above as the reason. It is not the best practice to catch all Exception as you may have a failure mode other than the one you are protecting against that will cause problems if the program continues.

You should remain using the `AsyncTask` and it will work

Comment: Thanks dude! `AsyncTask` was doing my job, but I was trying to do in `onCreate()` and don't know why it didn'y work. Thanks for explanation.